# Issue with react-native run-ios

Tags: ios, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I spent like 3-4 days trying to figure this out and I cant a solution to it. i googled around and can't find answer.

What happened was everytime I create a new file I get this error.
I used react-native init ProjectName. npm install. cd ios. pod install. cd ..
then react-native run-ios and this is what I get.

```
asdf@Asdf-MacBook-Pro ProjectName % react-native run-ios
info Found Xcode workspace "ProjectName.xcworkspace"
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace ProjectName.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme ProjectName -destination id=3A1A98EB-1D97-4DC2-967F-565F3971D608")
(node:16102) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

node --trace-warnings ...

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
  throw err;
  ^


Error: Cannot find module '/Users/asdf/Desktop/starter/ProjectName/...'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Things I already did

- I deleted node_modules and package-lock.json and npm install again.
- npm install -g react-native-cli && npm install -g react-native before npm install
- upgrade node, nvm, npm
- downgrade node, nvm, npm

current version

```
node v16.17.0
nvm 0.39.1
npm 7.24.2
```

Answer (score 0):

first apply what you see in the picture via xcode ,you need try this and try yarn ios, and u can try in terminal on your project/ios. arch -arm64 pod install

[image]

Comment: Hi, I am able to get to that screen on xcode. Everytime I open a project or create a new project xcode just freeze. is "arch -arm64 pod install" for m1? I use pod install on project/ios and the error still appear